# Is there a scope analyzer for Python?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis, lexical-scope, python-jedi

Given a python file, I want to find out all of the scopes and declarations for the identifiers in the file.

For example, given this file:

```
import a
from b import xyz

def my_func(g):
   print "2"

my_func(0)
a.function_in_a(3)
xyz(4)
```

I want the output to be:

- on line 7, `my_func` refers to `my_func` defined in line 4 of this file
- on line 8, `a` refers to the module a. `function_in_a` refers to the function defined in module a
- on line 9, `xyz` refers to the function defined in module b

Is there a library that does this for me? Basically I'm trying to use the in the context of IDE functionality / code autocomplete / understanding scopes of variables. Basically, I'm interested in understanding the location of an identifier's (variable, function, etc) definition, much like how an IDE like PyCharm determines it.

Comment: There are no declarations in Python only definitions (name bindings). If a name doesn't refer to an object; it is NameError/UnboundLocalError. Look at jedi, rope libraries though Python is too dynamic to get the answer in all cases.

Comment: A package like flake8 figures this stuff out; at a lower level you can use the AST.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that I haven't seen this issue before.

There's `jedi.names`, which would do pretty much what you want!

https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/api.html#jedi.names